# Using RTM-API together with Events-api or Request

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am currently working on a slack bot and might require the use of both RTM api and Events or Request api.

1. Is there a way for RTM api and Events API to work together in a single python application?
2. Or would it have to be two python applications both connected a bot (is this possible?) and the events application would receive events while rtm receives all messages.

This is besides using RTM api and parsing all messages.

Comment: I don't see why it would not be possible to use both RTM and Events API in the same app, however it would be rather complex to setup. I would probably structure the app into 3 parts. RTM client, Events client, main app.

Comment: May I ask why you want to use both RTM and Events API? The functionality is mostly overlapping as you can see here: https://api.slack.com/events

Comment: Assuming you mean the Web API with "Request API": that is meant to be used in addition to RTM or Events API anyhow, since it provides access to different functionality

Comment: I would like to use Event's api for direct mentions, while RTM api is for looking through conversations for certain keywords. Also, I think I may have phrased that "request api" part wrongly. I actually meant slash command can be used together with events adapter in the same app as it uses flask, unlike the rtm client.

Comment: If you want to look for keywords in conversations, you can do that with the events API too. You can just subscribe to message events. So if you can I would suggest to stick with the events API, which works great together with slash commands and API calls, since they all use HTTP.